# Reading different type of file with template class

Tags: c++

I would like to create my first template class for files manipulation. To be more specific I started with.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
Foo();
~Foo();

std::vector<Foo<T>> vec;

void parsing(T&v,T&filename);


};

template<typename T>
inline Foo<T>::Foo()
{
}

template<typename T>
inline Foo<T>::~Foo()
{
}

template<typename T>
inline void Foo<T>::parsing(T&v, T&filename){

std::fstream file;
file.open(filename, std::ios_base::in)
if (plik.good()){
    typename T::value_type tmp;
    while (!plik.eof()){
        plik >> tmp;
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
    file.close();
    }
}
```

And then I wanted to do those kind of initialization.

```
Foo<std::string> file;
file.parsing(vec,"file.txt");
```

I'm kinda new with templates so I've got following questions.

1. How to read/save generic types of files ? My plan was to read a file, counting words, or numbers, and pushing this into Foo-type vector. Then after manipulation on an vector I wanted to save a results of counting.
2. How about constructors and intitialization of variables and vectors ? Is there any specific rules that I should follow with in template class ?

Sorry for this chaotic style of question but I  dont't know how to start. 
Thanks for all responses.

Comment: Mandatory read: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close. The example how you want to use your module looks good, it just doesn't match the function prototype.
Change your `parsing()` function like this:

```
void Foo<T>::parsing(std::vector<T>& v, const std::string& filename);
```

Regarding your questions:

1. Your solution is one type to do it. Just the vector should not be a vector of `Foo`'s, but of `T`'s.
2. Initialisation of variables is not different in a template than that in a normal class.

Comment: okay thanks for advice. it really helped me. I've changed a little bit my this code but your declaration is great. Now I have another kind of problem. When I want to read <char> type I have to use some buffer and reading this character by character with file.get(buffer). If I want to read <string> type I have to use same construction but with getline. And my question. How to make specialization of template for approprietly type ? I read about this a little bit but my ways of doing it was incorrect. By the way I'm reallly grateful for support

Comment: What you are looking for is a partial template specialisation: `template<> class Foo<std::string> ...`. There you can implement the special handling. But you have to implement all methods from the template Foo<>, not just the ones that are special for std::string.

Comment: And: If my answer helped you, why not upvote it? :-)

Comment: I upvoted but I don't have any rank so thats why It's not visible :X